# Best way to manage user permissions with PHP

Tags: php, security, permissions

What is the best way to manage user permissions whith PHP  ..

1) By using **new table** ?
`table user_permissions (id, userId, addNews, editNews, deleteNews, ...)`
The type of every properties column is *boolean* (1 => yes, 0=>no)

2) By using **logic gates** ?

```
$addNews = 1; 
$editNews = 2;  
$deleteNews = 4;
 ...
$permissions = $addNews | $editNews | $deleteNews | ...;

//Save permission in user table
//and save it in session on login to test permission in every page

$permissions = $_SESSION['permissions'];
if($permissions & 1) // true -> user has permission to add news
```

**Or you have another way ?**

Comment: New table. This way the user can't manipulate it (There are tools for editing cookies you know) so it's more secure. And it's also easily manageable (using a back-end panel for instance, instead of editing a file)

Comment: session not saved in cookies ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no best way. Each solution depends on how you want to use it.

For example, at least following questions you need to answer:

- How many permissions you have?
- Are they hierarchical (guest -> user- > admin -> super admin) or not? (One user have access to write news, but not delete them, for example.)

Nevertheless, it would be easier to have one point in your code where you check permissions.

```
function havePermission($name){
// logic
}
```

NEVER! Do any inline permission checks inside your code. This is bad habbit.

In addition, there are actually three ways how to store permissions:

1. New table (or your main users table) like you provided:

   `userId, accessNews, accessPages, etc`
2. New table, however, with different structure:
   `userId, permissionId`
3. Main user table, one field:
   `userId, groupId`
   OR
   `userId, access`

   In this solution, in access you write access matrix that you can check using boolean logic.